# Generate function from data

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I have a series of inputs and outputs :

Inputs -> Outputs

```
1,2,3 -> 4
4,5,6 -> 5
7,8,9 -> 6
```

Is there a field of study that can generate a single function with approximate coefficients and operators for the inputs to generate the outputs. This new function can accept the inputs from the data set and provide an approximate solution if exact solution cannot be found.

An area of study I'm aware of that could generate a function from this data is genetic programming but are there others ? Can discrete optimization be applied to this problem ?

Comment: For the given example, you could use $f(x)=3+\left\lceil\frac{x}{3}\right\rceil$. For the general case, I suggest that you look into [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Do you just mean general [curve/data fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)? These are generally done by first prescribing a finite dimensional ansatz (a template function with finitely many coefficients) and then doing an optimization computation to find the "best fitting" (you have to define what that means) candidate.

Comment: @Willie Wong yes, data fitting. "best fitting"  in my case means the function that closest approximates the output value based on the input value

Comment: For rational functions try Pade approximation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant